# Autocomplete or filter from a list created by a SQL Command

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How would I include a text box or a command that allows the user to begin typing two or 3 letters in a text box and the result autocomplete and display in the panel?

I appreciate all of the help. I am having to include code to a project that uses many components that perform financials for a large university library. This may seem simple to some, but when I have used code that completes the autocomplete, other components log errors. So I am having to code around other funding/financial pages. I apologize if my questions seem to "demonstrate minimal understanding

Here is my code:

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~main.master" %>
 <script runat="server">

protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sqlBooks.Insert();
    txtNewBook.Text = String.Empty;
    gvBooks.DataBind();
}
 </script>
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphMain" Runat="Server">
 <div id="awindow" >
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="mainContent">
<div style="width: 100%; float: left">    
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl=" "  Width="100%"/>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server"  style="margin-left:5px; float:left;" ID="txtNewTitle" />
    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnAddTitle" Height="17px" ToolTip="Add New Book"      ImageUrl="~insert.png" OnClick="btnAd_Click"/>
</div>
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="sqlBookLibs" ConnectionString="<%$   ConnectionStrings:dbbooks %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AllBooks.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM BookTitles ORDER BY Titles" 
    InsertCommand="BookTitles_GetOrCreate" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtNewTitle" Name="titlename" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvBooks" DataSourceID="sqlBookTitles" DataKeyNames="BookTitles" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Book Name"  DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/BookTitles/Books.aspx?id={0}" DataNavigateUrlFields="PartnerID" DataTextField="BookName" />
        </Columns>
        <Columns>
             <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Find Book Titles"  DataNavigateUrlFields="" DataTextField="" />

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Have you tried searching the internet at all for this?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ is a good place to start pretty straight forward

Comment: I appreciate all of the help.  I am having to include code to a project that uses many components that perform financials for a large university library.  This may seem simple to some, but when I have used code that completes the autocomplete, other components log errors.  So I am having to code around other funding/financial pages.  I apologize if my questions seem to "demonstrate minimal understanding."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this; you can use the `AutoCompleteCustomSource`, `AutoCompleteMode` and `AutoCompleteSource` properties for the control in question (click the control and press F4).

Or, you can do it at run-time like this:

```
yourTextBoxNameHere.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.AllSystemSources;
yourTextBoxNameHere.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestedAppend;
```

Or, you can load a custom source and databind it to your control:

```
yourTextBoxNameHere.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

Tutorials, [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/AutoCompletion02012006113508AM/AutoCompletion.aspx), [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2suYQr6ebI) and [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWVMEiKoY0g).

Comment: Thank you for the links to the tutorials.  They were very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible with existing server controls. You have to use certain controls just like JQuery Auto-complete or Ajax Auto-complete extender. For Jquery Auto-complete, you have to add js file apply its properties with the text-box. In case of, Ajax Toolkit Auto-complete extender, you have to add its reference into the project and then you can drag and drop the control next to your text-box. You have to set the property of that control such as "TargetControlID" and set ot to text-box ID.

Comment: Thanks so much for the above links! I am using jquery and, as a test included the below code: <script language = "javascript" type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
             source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]
         });
     });
  </script>
My input box:  h<input id="autocomplete" />
My error: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method.  The jslibraries exists.  Why the error?